# Calculus Rocket Problem

Tags: calculus

I have an older Calculus book that I'm using to prepare for Calculus II.  I'm just trying to brush up on some things.  I find I often get thrown off by word problems.

"An object increases in height x above the surface of the earth, its weight w decreases because the pull of gravity on the object decreases.  Suppose that a rocket weighs 80/(x + 4000)^2 million pounds at an altitude of x miles and is rising at the constant rate of 100 mi/min.  Find the rate of change of weight with respect to time at any instant."

I'm given the answer dw/dt = -16,000/(x + 4000)^3, but I'm not sure how to arrive at this answer.

I suspect this has something to do with the Chain Rule.  I know the derivative of (x + 4000)^2 = 2(x + 4000), gravity is s = 16t^2 and that the acceleration of the rocket is a=100.  The velocity of the rocket would be v(t)=100t and the distance would be d(t) = 50t^2.  Unfortunately I am not able to put everything together to solve this equation.

Answer (score 1):

We have $w = \displaystyle \frac{80}{(x+4000)^2}$, so

$\displaystyle\frac{dw}{dt} = -\frac{160}{(x + 4000)^3}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

We are given that the rocket changes in height at a constant rate of $100$ miles per pinute. So thus $\frac{dx}{dt} = 100$.

Then $\displaystyle\frac{dw}{dt} = -\frac{160}{(x + 4000)^3}\frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{16,000}{(x + 4000)^3}$, as desired.

Comment: David, thanks for the quick response.  This makes sense. I was able to use the quotient rule to get -160/(x+4000)^3.

Comment: Charles, you don't even need to use the quotient rule there, but simply the chain rule. You have $-160(x+4000)^{-2}$ and can simply apply the chain rule. Of course, quotient rule works too, but is more cumbersome. Glad I could help!

Comment: So it seems that the initial equation should be dw/dx = -160/(x+4000)^3?  You put dw/dt.  And using the Chain Rule we'd have dw/dt = dx/dt * dw/dx?

Comment: Right, the Chain Rule from the start would have been much easier.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No, what I have is right. What I wrote was $\frac{dw}{dt} = \frac{dw}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}$, where I actually wrote out $\frac{dw}{dx}$. I should've been more clear.